# Angular8 cannot read property of 'valid' of undefined for the form

Tags: html, angular, validation, typeerror

I am using register form for adding employee.. and using validation for this. but for some reason, it's giving me an error

"cannot read property of 'valid' of undefined "

These are my code

HTML

```
<div  class="container" style="background-color: gainsboro;">

    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" #form=ngForm (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit(form.value)">
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <br>
            <select formControlName="jobid" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.jobid.errors }">
                <option value="">Select Job</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of this.jobList" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.jobid.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.jobid.errors.required">Job is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <br>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Joining Date" formControlName="date" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.date.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.date.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.date.errors.required">Joining Date is required</div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

        <div class="form-row">

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }"  pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*"/>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                    <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.pattern">Please enter a correct name</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }"  pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*"/>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                    <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.pattern">Please enter a correct name</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btnborder">Register</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

ts file

```
export class NewEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private service:NewEmployeeService) { 
    this.getJobs()
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      jobid: ['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],

  }, {
      // validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
  });
  }

 get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

 onSubmit(event:any) {

    console.log(event)
     this.submitted = true;

     // stop here if form is invalid
     if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
          return;
      }
    Swal.fire("Successfull","New employee registration is successfull","success")
 }
  public jobList:any=[]
  public getJobs()
  {
    this.service.getJobList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.jobList=data;
    })
  }

}
```

whenever i use this code
***(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"***
validation is working and also the null value is passing..

when i use this

**(ngSubmit)="f.valid &&(ngSubmit)"**

validation is not working and the submit function is also not working

and this this error shows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error message, because `get f(){...}` does not return a `FromGroup`. It's returning the `controls` object of the `FromGroup` and this object does not have a `form` attribute defined. 
And because of this you're getting the error message `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`.

You should use your `FormGroup` directly:

```
(ngSubmit)="registerForm.valid && onSubmit(form.value)"
```

**Update:**

As I can see in your provided stackblitz the validation is working. Your error class `is-invalid` is only applied if the form is submitted, which you do, when the form is invalid.

So you should change the applying of your error class or add another boolean, which is set to true, when you click on the submit button.

*First option*

```
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.jobid.errors }"
```

*Second Option (imo recommended)*

In your HTML:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
```

And in your component:

```
onSubmit(event:any) {

    console.log(event)
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is not valid
    // RECOMMENDATION Use !FromGroup.valid, because with async validation neither valid nor invalid is set
    if (!this.registerForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    Swal.fire("Successfull","New employee registration is successfull","success")
```

}

In this case the submitted flag is set to true and your error class is applied correctly.

Comment: Please provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com), so I can have a better look on this

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the below code
get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
change to return this.registerForm

Comment: Form got submitted  when i tried.Also use safe navigation operator to avoid the below error
Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `registerForm.valid` condition from your `(ngSubmit)` event inside `form` tag. This condition is preventing you to submit the form and your validations are not working.

Simply write:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
```

Comment: whenever i use this code (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" validation is working and also the null value is passing..

Comment: It will not pass the `null` values. You are seeing `null` values on console because you have put your `console.log(event)` at wrong place. You should place it after `if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
         return;
     }`